# trainning neural network

Tags: neural-network

I have a picture.1200*1175 pixel.I want to train a net(mlp or hopfield) to learn a specific part of it(201*111pixel) to save its weight to use in a new net(with the same previous feature)only without train it to find that specific part.now there are this questions :what kind of nets is useful;mlp or hopfield,if mlp;the number of hidden layers;the trainlm function is unuseful because "out of memory" error.I convert the picture to a binary image,is it useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly do you need the solution to do?  Find an object with an image (like "Where's Waldo"?).  Will the target object always be the same size and orientation?  Might it look different because of lighting changes?

If you just need to find a fixed pattern of pixels within a larger image, I suggest using a straightforward correlation measure, such as crosscorrelation to find it efficiently.

If you need to contend with any of the issues mentioned above, then there are two basic solutions: 1. Build a model using examples of the object in different poses, scalings, etc. so that the model will recognize any of them, or 2. Develop a way to normalize the patch of pixels being examined, to minimize the effect of those distortions (like Hu's invariant moments).  If nothing else, yuo'll want to perform some sort of data reduction to get the number of inputs down.  Technically, you could also try a model which is invariant to rotations, etc., but I don't know how well those work.  I suspect that they are more tempermental than traditional approaches.

Answer (score 0):

I found [AdaBoost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdaBoost) to be helpful in picking out only important bits of an image. That, and resizing the image to something very tiny (like 40x30) using a Gaussian filter will speed it up and put weight on more of an area of the photo rather than on a tiny insignificant pixel.

Comment: thanks for your attention.pleas help me more.i want to write a code for it. if it possible please explain any more.

Comment: Sorry bud. Neural nets and this kinda stuff are a difficult subject. You're going to have to do some reading on it.

Comment: Hi . I read hagan book and something else dear. i dont know anything about adaboost. if you have anything to help me i want it. thanks alot for your time.

Comment: you can read my paper http://www.mva-org.jp/Proceedings/2009CD/papers/01-03.pdf it briefly describes how we did some image (rather video) classification. not sure how much help it'll be though